# Godot - Get physics fps from script?

Tags: game-physics, godot

So I want to set a speed in pixels per second and then calculate how much to move that specific physics frame. something like `const speed = 500 / get_physics_fps()`, I could in fact just do:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    var speed = 500 * delta
```

but it feels like kind of a waste to calculate every frame something we know isn't going to change, also I can just divide by 60 or whatever I set my physics fps to, but that would be kind of harder to mantain than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the physics FPS from [ProjectSettings](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_projectsettings.html#class-projectsettings-property-physics-common-physics-fps):

```
var fps = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/common/physics_fps")
```

However, it is extremely common to calculate translation by multiplying `speed` by `delta` in `_physics_process`. Choosing some unusual alternative is just going to make your project more confusing, and is only worthwhile if you've *already identified a performance bottleneck* directly related to this. If you haven't, you're falling into the [premature optimization trap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/59232), wasting time and headspace optimizing things that don't matter, meaning you won't have time to optimize the things that *do* matter later.

Answer (score 2):

The property you're looking for is `Engine.iterations_per_second`, which can be read from and written to at runtime:

```py
var speed = 500.0 / Engine.iterations_per_second
```

Alternatively, you can read any of your project settings via `ProjectSettings.get_setting()`, however keep in mind modifying your project settings at runtime won't do anything, and reading them at runtime won't reflect any changes that may have happened since the engine was initialized, so I'd advise against it unless absolutely necessary.

That said, I strongly advise you stick with the delta method, partially because attempting to hard-code your velocity is a tremendously superfluous premature optimization, partially because it's standard practice, and partially because multiplying by delta lets you use `Engine.time_scale` to implement things like slow-motion without having to jump through nightmarish special case code.